# What does the VC++ "Exclude Directories" project setting actually do?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, project, visual-studio-2015, projects-and-solutions

I am attempting to use the new VS2015 [precompiled header refactoring tool](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e6ca02bb-1c89-4ccc-bada-fb772cf122bd). When I launch it, it pops up a message saying:

> To improve recommendations, add third party library paths to the
>   'Exclude Directories' property under VC++ Directories (in the Project
>   Properties dialog).

I'm not clear on precisely what a directory is being excluded from if I list it here. All the [MSDN help text](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(VC.Project.VCDirectories.ExecutablePath)&rd=true) has to say about it is:

> Directories not to search when checking for build dependencies

That helps a little, but I'm still not completely sure about what functionality I will gain/lose if I list something here. Something like, say, boost (which the message from the pch tool seems to be suggesting). Can anyone say exactly what this setting does?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general idea is that every time you hit 'Build' the IDE (or msbuild more specifically) has to check all the dependencies to see which cpp files need to be rebuilt.  If you have a large project and many headers (boost being a good example) then this may have to check for thousands of headers (because each header also needs to have its dependencies checked).

If you have a third party library such as boost which is only updated very rarely then you can add the path to the Exclude box so that the dependency checker won't bother checking any of those libraries.  **However**, if you *do* update the library at some point, or make a small change to it then you will have to manually rebuild all projects that relied on it, because you have told the build system not to do it for you.

In practice I've never found it to be a problem, even with a few MLOC project and a boost installation, especially if you're building with an SSD.  If you're on older hardware then it may be worth using, but I think it may cause problems when you inevitably forget to rebuild dependent projects.

Comment: If you keep your Boost installations in numbered directories (e.g. `C:\Boost\boost_1_55_0`) and reference this via a `Boost.props` file in your project directories, then updating Boost just creates a second directory, and using the upgraded Boost version is a one-line change to the .props file which triggers the necessary rebuild of projects (i.e. only those that actually reference your boost.vsprops)

Comment: Nice suggestion. I really like the use of `.props` files for solutions with many projects